# How can I change where lazy-loading Angular 2 looks for chunks?

Tags: angular, webpack

I have set up lazy loading in my Angular 2 project using the loadChildren syntax. The problem I have is that after chunks are created, the browser doesn't seem to know where to look to find them. It always tries to load chunks from the root directory, e.g. `http://localhost:55626/1.chunk.js`. This is of course not where they're stored.

I've been able to work around this issue by bundling the chunks using the .NET bundler, but of course this means they're all loaded at start and defeats the purpose of using lazy loading. I'm guessing that this is an issue with webpack defaulting to look in the wrong place for chunks created during `ng build` but I'm not confident about that, and even if I'm right, I understand that projects built with angular-cli currently do not support a custom webpack.config.js.

Can anyone shed some insight on this problem? Thanks!

I am using Angular 2.4.6.

Edit: To clarify, I build this project using angular-cli, which doesn't support custom webpack.config files, per https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1656#issuecomment-240171375

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out there is a setting in the angular-cli.json file that controls this:

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "deployUrl": "./path/to/files/"
    }
  ]
}
```

I believe `deployUrl` should point to the sources output by `ng build` so they can be bundled up as needed by angular-cli. Note that the path *must* end in a slash ("/") for lazy-loading to work.

Adding this property fixed the problem for me and I am now loading as lazily as I do everything else.

See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5652

Comment: THANK YOUUUU `Note that the path must end in a slash ("/") for lazy-loading to work`

Comment: I'm using a custom webpack.config file. In my use case i want the chunks to be loaded from a CDN. Adding the deployURL in angular-cli.json did not solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

Chunks can be found by configuring webpack with [angular2-router-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-router-loader). to do so:

Install angular2-router loader

`npm install --save-dev angular2-router-loader`

Add the loader to your webpack

```
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.ts$/,
    loaders: [
      ‘awesome-typescript-loader’, 
      ‘angular2-template-loader’, 
      ‘angular2-router-loader’]
   },
   ...
]
```

Then, webpack should automatically know how to load and find your chunks.

Comment: As far as I can tell, projects using angular-cli (like mine) can't use custom webpack.config files. See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1656#issuecomment-240171375